# Can you grow more Biomass in a brickhouse only powered by solar cells than in a greenhouse? Will we ever be able to?

Tags: energy, visible-light, photons, light-emitting-diodes

Right now I read that 1m² of solar cells generates roughly 100Watts of energy. There are really efficient Grow LEDs that use only [two spikes in the lightspectrum to make plants grow.](http://static3.shopify.com/s/files/1/0002/0948/files/growledgraph.gif)

I have seen some graphs like the [Quantum Efficiency of Sola Cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_efficiency#Quantum_efficiency_of_solar_cells)
that suggest that solar cells can absorb energy in the range of 400nm up to 1200nm (in varying degrees of efficiency).

By my logic (given a high enough overall efficiency of the solar cell), a solar cell can make light that is most of the time reflected by plants in the range of e.g. 500nm-600nm / or 800nm+, into electrical energy, and that electrical energy can be used, in turn, to produce light in the range of 400nm and 700nm that the plants can use again for photosynthesis.

Additionally, i could imagine that the sun sometimes hits the range of diminishing returns in terms of brightness (lux, lumen?) when it's really really bright and hot and shining directly on the plants. Instead it would maybe be more efficient to capture that energy (photon) and convert them only to the wavelength needed in enough brightness that plants can grow (again, given a high enough solar cell efficiency, right now it's 20%, i heard 40% is a theoretical limit?)

You could phrase the question a little bit different: I have 1m² of land and two possibilities:

1. build a greenhouse and plant 1m² of crops
2. build a brickhouse as high as I want with as many layers of 1m² levels. But they are only allowed to be lighted with LEDs and no direct sunlight. And the LEDs are only allowed to be powered by 1m² of solar cell on the roof.

What is the needed solar cell efficiency (generated watts/m²) for the solar cell to reach the break even point of total biomass production / timeunit between case 1. and 2.

If there are other environmental conditions that would benefit only one of these cases, assume in favor of case 2 and mention the variable.

I was in a heated discussion about this yesterday and I would love for someone who knows more then me to help me wrap my head around this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great question. I worry that the correct answer needs to reach into biophysics more deeply than we usually do on this site - but in principle you are right that a lot of solar power is reflected by plants; if you have a really efficient solar cell that converts all incident energy to electricity, and you use this to illuminate plants at their peak sensitivity, it would do better. A solution would have two properties: the solar panel has to look black, and there should be relatively little reflection from the plant at the illumination wavelength

Comment: You are right. I posted the same question on the Biology stack exchange. The best bet is to find someone who knows both fields sufficiently well

Comment: Based on your comment, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more about biology or biophysics

Comment: Perhaps better: "generates energy at a 100 watt rate"?

Nitpicking mode off...

Comment: You are on to something, even though the implementation is more complicated than needs to be. Many plants can absorb a lot of light for a short amount of time if you give them a rest phase during which they can rebuild their light damaged photosynthesis molecules. This allows for "rotating" stacked greenhouses, which expose the top row of potted plants for an hour, or so, before rotating them out of the direct light. That plants "like" greenhouses is also because most of the damaging UV is gone, so they have to spend less energy on damage repair.

Comment: That's a lot of Information that I hadn't had before, I studied up on the solar cell physics side of the question but there is way less I know about photosynthesis! Thanks for the info bits. So is there a way how I can answer this better? Like is there something like a Maximum-Energy-Exposure before the plants need to rest, or is there a technical terminology for something like that so I can google for something specific? :)

Comment: http://getguesstimate.com/models/2648

These are my calculations so far but I'm still missing some vital points of information. I'm lacking a complete foundation of basic Unit knowledge (like what I can do with Photon Flux or the Irradiance etc) to manipulate the data in a meaningful way. I mean, I learnt a lot today and I can read up on all of this but before I feel I can put all the puzzle pieces together I should read 1-2 physics books and atleast 1 book on photosynthesis. On the left side are my sources